# Is it safe to set python bin in $PATH to another python version?

Tags: python, debian, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda3 just now, and I noticed that now, when I run `python` command from terminal, `Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)|` is starting. Anaconda installer had added path to anaconda dir in `$PATH` and there is symlink from `python` to `python3.5`

My question is: will programs, that depends from python command and expects python2, work correctly, or I should remove symlink `python` from anaconda dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: will programs, that depends from python command and
>   expects python2, work correctly?

Those programs should use full path of the python binary. Something like `/usr/bin/python`, and so `$PATH` is irrelevant. As long as you don't change `/usr/bin/python`, nothing will break.

If you remove the stuff that Anaconda has added, it's likely that Anaconda will not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your OS. [Debian and Ubuntu both have ongoing projects to move the "default" version from 2 to 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python) (also [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/Python35Transition)). But it's not recommended to point /usr/bin/python to python3 if Python 2 is installed (see [PEP 394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#recommendation)).

If you want 'python' to be pointing to your 3.x install, you could use an alias (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/make-default-python-command-to-use-python-3)). This way you can use python in your session and at least don't change it on the whole system.

Comment: Sorry, just read the question again and realised that was not quite what you've asked. And honestly I'm not sure if this will brake anything. But I would assume that at least all system critical stuff will use /usr/bin/python or python3 directly.